# ElasticSearch: aggregations for ip_range type

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field which is defined in mappings as:

```
"route": {
  "type": "ip_range"
}
```

It works well, and I see the results when I query the ES:

```
"_source": {
  "ip": "65.151.40.164",
  "route": "65.151.40.0/22",
  ...
}
```

Now I want to do some aggregations of this field, and pretty much everything I try ends up being this error:

```
"caused_by": {
  "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
  "reason": "Fielddata is not supported on field [route] of type [ip_range]",
  "caused_by": {
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Fielddata is not supported on field [route] of type [ip_range]"
  }
}
```

I hope that it doesn't mean that ES doesn't support aggregations for `ip_range`? Or if it does, how can it be done?

**UPDATE**

As I said, so far *any* aggregations that work on other types (including `ip` type) don't work on `ip_range`.

Some examples:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "routes": {
      "range": {
        "field": "route",
        "ranges": [
            {"to": "10.0.0.0/32"}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "routes": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "route",
        "size": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone can point me to an aggregation that *does* work on `ip_range` that would be helpful!

Comment: How would you like to aggregate documents? Can you add sample docs and expected result?

Comment: Can you show the aggregation you're trying to run?

Comment: @NishantSaini, @Val I added some examples. Can you show me an example of aggregation that _does_ work for `ip_range`?

Answer (score 0):

There's a specific [`ip_range`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-iprange-aggregation.html) aggregation for the `ip_range` field type, i.e. do not use the `range` aggregation (only for numeric types) and `terms` (only for numeric and keyword types):

```
GET /ip_addresses/_search
{
    "size": 10,
    "aggs" : {
        "routes" : {
            "ip_range" : {
                "field" : "route",
                "ranges" : [
                    {"to": "10.0.0.0/32"}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's for `ip` type, not for `ip_range`? Doesn't work on `ip_range` for me.